# What is the regex to match alphanumeric 6 character words, separated by space or comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I am newbie in RegEx and trying to design a RegEx which could match the String like below:

pattern 1 separated by comma and a space: `KEPM39, JEMGH5, HEPM21` ... (repeat)

pattern 2 separated only by a space: `KEPM39 JEMGH5 HEPM21` ... (repeat)

pattern 3 separated only by a comma: `KEPM39,JEMGH5,HEPM21` ... (repeat)

this is my concept: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}[,\s]+$"` but it seems wrong.

#I want to validate the whole string, and I use javascript & html to validate user input. (textarea)

#duplicate change to repeat to be more suitable.

```
function validate(){
    var term = "JEPM34, KEPM11 ";
    var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}[,\s]+$");
    if (re.test(term)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

thanks you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to split the whole string **or** validate the whole string? Can you include your desired results? Also, what do you mean with "Duplicate"? It may also help to include what app you are using.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: thank you sir, I have modified my content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want consistent delimiters, and there can be trailing spaces (as there is in your example data) you can use a capture group with a backreference `\1` to keep consistent delimiters and match optional spaces at the end.

Note that you can also use `\s` but that could also match a newline.

Using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will return a boolean, so you don't have to use return true or false but you can return the result test`

```
^[A-Z\d]{6}(?:(, ?| )(?:[A-Z\d]{6}\1)*[A-Z\d]{6} *)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z\d]{6}` Match 6 occurrences of a char A-Z or a digit
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `(, ?| )` Capture **group 1**, match either a comma and optional space, or a space to be used as a backreference
  - `(?:[A-Z\d]{6}\1)*` Optionally repeat any of the listed followed by a backreference `\1` to group 1 which will match the same delimiter
  - `[A-Z\d]{6} *` Match any of the listed and optional spaces at the end
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional to also match an instance without delimiters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yGER5l/1)

```js
const regex = /^[A-Z\d]{6}(?:(, ?| )(?:[A-Z\d]{6}\1)*[A-Z\d]{6} *)?$/;
const validate = term => regex.test(term);

[
  "KEPM39, JEMGH5, HEPM21",
  "KEPM39 JEMGH5 HEPM21",
  "KEPM39,JEMGH5,HEPM21",
  "JEPM34, KEPM11 ",
  "JEPM34, KEPM11",
  "JEPM34",
  "KEPM39, JEMGH5 HEPM21, HEGD44    ZZZZZZ",
  "KEPM39, JEMGH5 HEPM21"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} ==> ${validate(s)}`)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

A very loose way to validate could be:

```
^[A-Z\d]{6}(?:[ ,]+[A-Z\d]{6})*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqvok7/1). With loose, I meant that `[ ,]+` is not checking that each delimiter in your string is the same per definition. Therefor even `"KEPM39, JEMGH5 HEPM21, HEGD44    ZZZZZZ"` would be valid.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much. But in javascript the result seems  not expected: https://jsfiddle.net/e5d31hgt/

Comment: @Howard, I don't know how to fix it in code, maybe you can use the code-generator in the online demo I provided. My know-how about JS is not good enough to advise you further.